# SSIS Automation

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I came across a good SSIS and SQL Problem. How do I in SSIS create a package that will execute a SQL query in management studio and grab the results of that query *(the query results are "Insert INTO statements")* and run that insert into statement query results into another sql database within SSIS that updates a table in another server? *(The first query runs in one database and the second query runs in a different database)*

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Basically this is what I want the package to do. Execute a sql task in one step. Then that step will store the results and use the results from the first sql task into the second sql task and run it on a different database . How would the data flow task look like  ? Two “Execute Sql tasks “ then a “Ole DB Source?  I’m trying to make this an automated step into a sql job on a daily basis without me doing it manually.

Comment: @BobOrdell Can you please post the queries you're mentioning here. When you are saying that the query results are "Insert into statements" one can interpret that you want to run some dynamic sql query on one server and execute the result on another. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sql queries execute on the database, not management studio. Management studio is visual interface for configuring,managing and administer databases.

To me it doesn't sound like there's any problem here at all. Create one connection manager for each DB.  Then create two "Execute SQL Tasks", put your insert statements in them use use your connection manangers you've created.

Answer (score 0):

Run the first query in an Execute SQL task and store the results in a string variable.

Then run a second Execute SQL task, using the variable as your SQL command.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would the data flow look like ? For example, two “execute sql tasks” followed by a ole db source ? Also how would I store the results in a string variable and use those results in a second sql task ?

Comment: The data flow would look like an execute sql task, and a precedence constraint pointing to another execute sql task.   If you google your second question you will find examples.

Answer (score 0):

Create Connection Managers for each of the databases you need, your source and both (or all) destinations.

Create a Data Flow Task.

In your OLEDB Source, execute your `SELECT` statement.

Pump the results into a MultiCast Transformation. This allows you to send the exact same result set to multiple destinations.

Create a Destination for each table you want to write to, and connect them to the MultiCast.

Bob's your uncle.

Comment: How would the data flow look like ? For example I would start with a “ole db source “ Then drag a Multicast Transformation and OLE DB Destination from the Toolbox ?